# How to use foreach in jstl + javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, tomcat, jstl

I try add pin in Google map. I have collection `${list}` items with coordinate and name. Everyone item I want put in map. I write some code:

```
<script>
function initMap() {
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
    var cairo = {lat: ${item.geometry.lat}, lng: ${item.geometry.lng}};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        scaleControl: true,
        center: cairo,
        zoom: 10
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    infowindow.setContent('${item.name}');
</c:forEach>
}
```

But my code don't work correct. This add in map only one (last) item from collection.

Please help.

Comment: Rightclick page in browser, choose *View Source*. Look carefully there. How exactly should the final JS code look like? Once you figure out that, simply rewrite JSP/JSTL as such that it generates exactly the desired JS code output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may need create a Marker  point to map

```
function initMap() {

var cairo =new google.maps.LatLng(38.54,77.02); 

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    scaleControl: true,
    center: cairo,
    zoom: 10
});

<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

infowindow.setContent('${item.name}');

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(${item.geometry.lat}, ${item.geometry.lng});

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position : myLatlng,
    map : map,
    icon : 'img/icon.png' 
    title:${item.name}
   }); 
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {  
    // map.setZoom(15);  
    // map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());  
     infowindow.open(map, marker);  
    });  
  </c:forEach>

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this way and it works. I hope that helps.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    /* Markers information
       KONUME & KONUMB = latLng & numbers in database
       numbers can be left unquoted. */
    var markers = [
       <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
                   ['<c:out value="${row.aciklama}" />',
                     <c:out value="${row.KONUME}" />,
                     <c:out value="${row.KONUMB}" />,
                     <c:out value="${row.EVID}" />,
                    '<c:out value="${row.aptadi}" />',
                    '<c:out value="${row.mahalle}" />',
                    '<c:out value="${row.sokak}" />',
                    '<c:out value="${row.durumu}" />',
                    '<c:out value="${row.metrekare}" />',
                    '<c:out value="${row.fiyat}" />',
                    '<c:out value="${row.odasayisi}" />'],
        </c:forEach>   ];  

     var map;
     /*<body onload="initialize()">*/
     function initialize() {

        var latlng= new google.maps.LatLng(38.675124,39.217375);

        var mapOptions = {
          center: latlng,
          zoom: 15,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);
        for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
           var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1],markers[i][2]);

           marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: position,
           map: map,
           title: markers[i][0],
           icon:image
        });
     }
</script>
```

**MyProjects**

[JSP + Google Maps API](https://github.com/gurkan0791/EmlakUygulama/blob/master/web/index.jsp)

[JSP + Angular + Google Maps API](https://github.com/gurkan0791/AngularGoogleMap/wiki)

---

> Fairly simple, is it? Take note that you still need those singlequotes around the variable; not for Java/JSP, but for JavaScript! Only pure number or boolean variables can be left unquoted.

See also [Java/JSP/JSF and JavaScript](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html)